# htaccess Faking directory path?

Tags: .htaccess, path

I would like to fake directory path with .htaccess, but I haven't got much experience with it, so I'm asking you, guys.

Let's say my URL is http://example.com/test and I got some scripts in that folder. I would like to hide the URL, so I wouldn't be able to access by it's real URL, but I could access it with e.g. http://example.com/test2.

I simply would like to hide and fake the directory.

Comment: If you just want to hide scripts, you can set a password with htaccess. Please ask if you would like me to show you how to do that.

Comment: oh, that's also great idea. Sure i want!

Comment: See [rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) rewrite /test to go to 403 ( `flag F` ), rewrite /test2 to /test on the filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simply protect the page with a password you can add the following into your .htaccess on the page you want to protect:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd <-- change this to your full path to .htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Then create the .htpasswd file, and create user/password combinations. Like this:

```
test:dGRkPurkuWmW2
```

Directions can be found on this page:

http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/password-protection/

Use a password generator like this one to generate an encrypted password:

http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/

Comment: Great, it works! However it gives me internal error 500 once I successfully log in.

Comment: 500 error is likely due to an error in your index.php, index.cgi or whatever other default page you are supposed to be seeing.

Comment: Try deleting the htaccess to see what if that caused the error.